# htaccess in subbdomain skip redirection rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm trying to let the visitors of my subdomain only direclty in, when using a specific subdomain link format. I know that this would block SEs too, but I don't want the subdomain to be indexed anyway.

The allowed link should look like this:

> subdomain.maindomain.com/aaa/bbb/ccc

and should be rewritten to this:

> subdomain.maindomain.com/index.php?a=aaa&b=bbb&c=ccc

everthing what's not of this form and coming from an empty or external referrer shall go to the main domain and without the variables:

maindomain.com/

I tried with all kind of configuration, my last .htaccess file in the subdomain folder looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?(\w{3})/(\w{3})/(\w{3})$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 [S=1,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?maindomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain\.com/ [L]
```

But it's still not doing what I want, it redirects also request for subdomain of the allowed form to the main domain and it also adds the vars as request to the main domain, going to this page

> maindomain.com/?a=aaa&b=bbb&c=cee

Can you help me with the condition defined above.

And a second question, about the performance: I could obviously do this verification / redirect with PHP, what would be more efficient in your opinion?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your logic correctly please try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Don't do any more rewrites if on index.php
# Note that you can add the HTTP_HOST condition here if you only want it to be active for the subdomain
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# If on subdomain then check that the referer is from main domain and attempt to match a regex
# If we find a match then ignore the next rule that rewrites subdomain to domain.com
# Basically this is like an awkward if-else statement..
# ================    

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(www\.)?domain\.com [NC]
# Rewrites /aaa/bbb/ccc to /index.php?a=aaa&b=bbb&c=ccc
RewriteRule ^(\w{3})/(\w{3})/(\w{3})$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 [S=1,L]

# Redirect all requests from subdomain to domain.com by default
# ================   

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com$
# Add the trailing question mark to delete all query parameters
RewriteRule .* http://domain.com/? [L]
```

Comment: Thank you, but no, still doesn't work.
Direct acces to http://subdomain.domain.com/aaa/bbb/cee still gets redirected to http://domain.com/

Comment: What doesn't work? Are you rewritten to domain.com from subdomain.domain.com? Note that I've updated the code quite a few times.

Comment: @user2176640 Please see my updated answer. We must add the `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]` directive on top because the `[L]` flag does not always do it's seemingly intended job of stopping all further rewrite processing.

Comment: Thank you. Using you last update, URLs without referrer of the format subdomain.maindomain.com/aaa/bbb/ccc still get redirected to maindomain.com . I'm starting to think that there might be an other configuration fault, maybe in apaches vhosts? Any ideeas?

Comment: @user2176640 Please try to comment out the `%{HTTP_REFERER}` condition to see if it is the culprit.

Comment: @user2176640 Cheers, I'm glad you sorted it out. Please mark my answer if it answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close. You need only a few additional parts

- The flag `S=1` doesn't harm, but is not necessary either.
- Move the referer condition to the first rule and invert it. You might want to allow for any subdomain as well.
- Add an additional negative condition to exclude `index.php` from being redirected to the main domain.
- You don't use the original request in the substitution in your second rule, so you don't need to capture it.
- Append a question mark `?` to prevent the arguments being forwarded to the main domain.
- Add an `R` flag, if you want the client to be redirected and not only the request rewritten.

All parts together

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(.+\.)?maindomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(\w{3})/(\w{3})/(\w{3})$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !$index\.php$
RewriteRule ^ http://domain\.com/? [R,L]
```

Regarding performance, if you rewrite or redirect with just .htaccess, the job is done before it even hits some PHP script. So, I think it is better to do this with .htaccess.

Comment: Thank you. URLs without referrer of the format subdomain.maindomain.com/aaa/bbb/ccc still get redirected to maindomain.com . I'm starting to think that there might be an other configuration fault, maybe in apaches vhosts? Any ideeas?

Comment: @user2176640 I thought, this is what you want. You wrote "everthing what's not of this form and coming from an empty or external referrer shall go to the main domain and without the variables"